# I have difficulty on testing else pattern in jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have responsibility for testing source code (javascript Vue). I have some problems with testing code for else pattern. Source code will be like

```
if (a !== null || a !== undefined) {
  ...
}
```

So I tested a value by assigning `null`, `undefined`, 2, string data. But the code branch show `else` condition is still missing. What data should I input for else condition passed?

Comment: Maybe something is happening with the type coercion since you use a triple operator. Could you try with "!=" instead of "!=="?

Comment: Are your sure you don't want an "and" condition there?

Comment: Btw, the second part of the condition (`|| a !== undefined`) has no effect. If you remove it, result will be the same.